# I am getting error on sending email with celery 'send' object has no attribute '__qualname__'

Tags: python, django

here is my code i am sending email after registeration using celery but i am getting error like

```
'send' object has no attribute '__qualname__'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'send' object has no attribute '__qualname__'
Exception Location: D:\DjangoPros\env\lib\site-packages\celery\local.py in __getattr__, line 143
Python Executable:  D:\DjangoPros\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path:    
['D:\\DjangoPros\\Blog',
 'D:\\DjangoPros\\env\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'c:\\users\\sudheer\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\sudheer\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\sudheer\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36',
 'D:\\DjangoPros\\env',
 'D:\\DjangoPros\\env\\lib\\site-packages',
 'D:\\DjangoPros\\Blog',
 '.']
Server time:    Wed, 29 Jul 2020 07:45:05 +0000
```

```
@shared_task
def send(user_name=None,to_email=None):
    try:
        sleep(1)
        username="user_name"
        html_message = loader.render_to_string(
            'security\mail_response.html',
            {
                'user_name': username,

        })

        subject="Hospectile Registration"
        message="Hello "+user_name+ 'You have registered sucessfully'
        from_email='smreddy475@gmail.com'
        to_list=(to_email,)


        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_list, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)

    except SMTPException as e:
        return e







@unauthenticated_user
def sign_up(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home_page')
    else:
        if request.method=='POST':
            try:
                print("Post data", request.POST)
                first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
                last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
                email = request.POST.get('email')
                username = request.POST.get('username')
                address = request.POST.get('address')
                password = request.POST.get('password')
                mobile = request.POST.get('mobile')
                user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name,email=email,
                                           username=username, password=password)
                user.profile.address = address

                user.profile.email = email
                user.profile.mobile = mobile
                user.profile.active = True
                user.is_staff = True
                user.save()
                send.delay(user_name=username,to_email=email)
                messages.info(request, "You have registred successfully!")
                return redirect('login')



            except Exception as e:l̥
                return HttpResponse(e)


        return render(request,'security/register.html')
```

Comment: which version celery you are using?

Comment: celery version celery==3.1.18

Comment: Reddy maybe you could upgrade celery.

Comment: now project is running but i am getting one more error signal only works in main thread